# ¿Es posible asignar el resto de valores desestructurados a un nuevo objeto sin crear un nuevo key?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy realizando la **desestructuración** de un objeto, para realizar un nuevo objeto que tendrá la mayoría de los valores.

ejemplo:

```js
const test = {
    a:'a',
    b:'b',
    c:'c',
    array:[
        {ar1:'1',ar2:'2'},
        {ar1:'2',ar2:'3'}
    ]
};
const {array,a, ...rest} = test;
const newObjet = {newData:array[0], rest};
console.log(newObjet);
```

Como en el nuevo objeto(`newObjet`) no me interesa que tenga `a` y `array` se realizo de esa manera, hasta ahí todo bien.

El problema es que no quiero que se cree un key `rest` en el nuevo objeto. el resultado que quiero es parecido a lo siguiente:

```
{
  newData: {
    "ar1": "1",
    "ar2": "2"
  },
   b: "b",
   c: "c"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta con que hagas:

```
const newObjet = {newData:array[0], ...rest};
```

Así también desestructuras el objeto rest y no te queda como una propiedad nueva

```js
const test = {
    a:'a',
    b:'b',
    c:'c',
    array:[
        {ar1:'1',ar2:'2'},
        {ar1:'2',ar2:'3'}
    ]
};
const {array,a, ...rest} = test;
const newObjet = {newData:array[0], ...rest};
console.log(newObjet);
```

Comment: No, lo desestructuras solo para leer el objeto test... pero no lo desestructuras cuando vas a crear el nuevo objeto. Revisa mi código.

Comment: @Richard Ya observó la salida en consola de mi código? es exactamente la que ud espera... que el objeto de respuesta no tenga la propiedad `rest`... no es eso lo que preguntaba?

Comment: he revisado y es correcto, mire que tiene `...` que son los que realizan la magia

Comment: Exacto, no es esa la respuesta que esperaba? su código no tiene los 3 puntos, el mio si. Su código incluye el `rest` como propiedad en la respuesta... el mio no.

Comment: Si es la respuesta que esperaba pero la pagina no me deja aceptarla, hasta que pasen 8 minutos

Comment: Ok, me alegra haberle podido ayudar ;)